# Tomcat Clustering and Load Balancing?

Tags: tomcat, load-balancing, cluster-computing

I have 3 tomcat servers where users get into all time. They are 3 because the processing of each request is heavy (lot of sql). Lusers enters to server 1 or 2 or 3. Now I want to make them "one". I know I need do clustering but, will clustering spread the requests thru the 3 servers or here is where I need implement load balancing with apache2 ?

Comment: Lusers? and you don't need clustering to spread requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hvae you tried this one: http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/04/14/clustering.html

Comment: I saw this tutorial, really doesn't response my answer directly but help me a lot with the clustering process, thanks